# Kendo DropDownTree filter does not display node children

Tags: kendo-ui, telerik, kendo-dropdown

I'm using the ASP.Net Core kendo DropDownTree displaying categories and product names under each category. The search filter works fine but when I search for a category name I need also to be able to display all the products under this category.

```
@(Html.Kendo().DropDownTreeFor(m => m.ProductTypeId)
                  .Filter(FilterType.Contains)
                  .HtmlAttributes(new { @class = @btnDisabledClass, style = "width:100%" })
                  .Events(ev => ev.Select("onProductTypeSelect"))
                  .Items(ddt =>
                  {
                      foreach (var productCategory in productCategories)
                      {
                          var pTypes = productTypes.Where(x => x.ProductCategoryId == productCategory.Id).ToList();
                          ddt.Add().Value(productCategory.Id.ToString()).Text(productCategory.GetDisplayName())
                          .Expanded(pTypes.Any(x => x.Id == Model.ProductTypeId))
                          .Items(r =>
                          {
                              foreach (var pType in pTypes)
                              {
                                  r.Add().Value(pType.Id.ToString()).Text(pType.GetDisplayName());
                              }
                          });
                      }
                  })
            )
```

- SmallCategory
- MedCategory
- BigCategory
- ```
      Cat3Product1
  ```
- ```
      Cat3Product2
  ```
- Category4

So in the search field, If I type : Big..
I need to have this result:

- BigCategory
- ```
      Cat3Product1
  ```
- ```
      Cat3Product2
  ```

Is it Doable?

Comment: Theoretically .Expanded(true) when the filter event is triggered will do the trick

Comment: @CarlosMartins Would you have an example on how to do it?

Comment: Here https://demos.telerik.com/aspnet-mvc/treeview/api you have an example how to expand all nodes with treeview.expand(".k-item"); Also please take a look at the events documentation and pick the best event to trigger it https://demos.telerik.com/aspnet-mvc/treeview/events

Comment: @CarlosMartins yes but the DropDownTree I'm using here doesn't have the "expand" method